# Export results from a mysql query to an excel sheet

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

```
<?php

  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.
  include 'includes/config.php'; 
  $filename = "PropertyAssetClass.xls"; // File Name

// Download file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$sql = "SELECT d.approved_comps as 'Approved Comps'
               FROM   properties.tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping a 
                      INNER JOIN properties.tblproperty b 
                              ON a.propertyid = b.propertyid 
                      INNER JOIN properties.tblmls_add_derived c
                              ON b.address = c.propertyaddress
                      INNER JOIN properties.tblcompdetails d
                              ON c.mlsnumber = d.mlsnumber
               WHERE  a.propertyassetclassid=$_GET[propertyassetclassid]";


$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$flag = false;
//echo $sql ."\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }      
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }


// ?>
```

I am trying to output the value of approved_comps to the excel sheet. When I run this code, the excel sheet is created but nothing is outputted. Not even the field name, Approved Comps, is displayed. I know for the fact this mysql query is legitimate. I can run this query without any syntax errors. Could it be that nothing is returned by the query? But still shouldn't it have the field name?

Comment: if the query does not return any values (empty result set), you won't output anything since the column names will be output inside your while loop (when you have data).

Comment: that makes sense. so I just need to figure out a way to rearrange the code such that the field name is not tied to the mysql output